# ICommand CanExecute not triggering after PropertyChanged?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

I got a **WPF application** that shows a button bound to a command like that:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=TestrunStartCommand}" Content="GO!">
```

The command is defined like that:

```
public ICommand TestrunStartCommand
{
    get { return new RelayCommand(TestrunStartExecute, () => !IsTestrunInProgress); }
}

public bool IsTestrunInProgress
{
    get{
        return _isTestrunInProgress;
    }
    set{
        _isTestrunInProgress = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(IsTestrunInProgressPropertyName);
    }
}
```

The problem is, the button won't be enabled immediately after I set `IsTestrunInProgress` to false, but *only after I click inside the application window*.

Could you help me understand this behaviour and show me how to fix this?

**Further reading:**
[wpf command pattern - when does it query canexecute](https://robburke.net/wpf-command-pattern-when-does-it-query-canexecute/)

Comment: `only after I click inside the application window`; are you implying that the currently active window in the OS is **not** this programs window? Or in other words, this application is up and running, but you're in Notepad and you can just see the window in the background.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud: No, the application window is active and has focus. It appears as if the `CanExecuteChanged` is only evaluated if I click inside my window.

Comment: RelayCommand from Galasoft library works effeciently

Comment: @HichemC I'm sure it works efficiently, the error certainly is on my (beginner) side. But where is my mistake?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

The `ICommand` interface exposes an event [`ICommand.CanExecuteChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecutechanged.aspx) which is used to inform the UI when to re-determine the `IsEnabled` state of command driven UI components.

Depending upon the implementation of the `RelayCommand` you are using, you may need to raise this event; Many implementations expose a method such as `RelayCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` which you can invoke to force the UI to refresh.

Some implementations of the `RelayCommand` make use of  [`CommandManager.RequerySuggested`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.requerysuggested.aspx), in which case you will need to call [`CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested.aspx) to force the UI to refresh.

Long story short, you will need to call one of these methods from your property setter.

**Update**

As the state of the button is being determined when the active focus is changing, I believe the `CommandManager` is being used. So in the setter of your property, after assigning the backing field, invoke [`CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested.aspx).

**Update 2**

The `RelayCommand` implementation is from the MVVM light toolkit. When consumed from WPF/.NET, the implementation wraps the methods and events exposed from the `CommandManager`. This will mean that these commands work automagically in the majority of situations (where the UI is altered, or the focused element is changed). But in a few cases, such as this one, you will need to manually force the command to re-query. The proper way to do this using this library would be to call the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` method on the `RelayCommand`.

Comment: You are right: I got the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method in my `RelayCommand`. But what I don't understand is that I got many working buttons and I _never_ raise this event manually, and somehow it works as if by magic. What is different in this case? I think there is still something missing in that puzzle...

Comment: And all these buttons are using the same implementation of `RelayCommand`? Could you perhaps tell me which implementation you are using? i.e. which library the class is from?

Comment: Yes all buttons use the same `RelayCommand`. I'm using the [mvvm light framework](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/).

Comment: It seems like when used from WPF, the `RelayCommand` merely uses the `CommandManager`, `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` is merely a wrapper around `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`. The exact requirements for the `CommandManager` to automatically raises `RequerySuggested` is not 100%. It usually occurs when focus changes or the UI changes. Perhaps the other buttons do something to this effect. Simply doing what I stated above should solve this problem for you. Why your other buttons work, I wouldn't be 100% sure without looking at the complete code.

Comment: If you're using WPF 4.5 or above, you need to use the RelayCommand from the namespace GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf instead of GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command. That will re-enable the RelayCommand to use the CommandManager.

Comment: I have the same behaviour as the OP, even using CommandWpf.RelayCommand and calling myCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged() right after changing the CanExecute condition. (The IsEnabled property updates only after clicking on the UI). WPF 4.0, MvvmLight 5.2.0.37222

Comment: I am not using any MVVM toolkit and get the same behavior. CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested(); is working for me.

Comment: Another important thing I noticed, if you set the (change-causing) property from a non-UI thread, you need to call the mentioned methods via the Dispatcher. Otherwise, WPF just swallows the notification.

Comment: @AndreasDuering thanks. Buttons get updated CanExecute just after subscription OnPropertyChanged and call RaiseCanExecuteChanged via Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke in event handler

Comment: @AndreasDuering Your suggestion on Dispatcher is what helped me.

Answer (score 62):

This is so important and easy to miss, I am repeating what @Samir said in a comment. Mr Laurent Bugnion wrote in his [blog](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2015/01/re-enabling-the-commandmanager-feature-with-relaycommand-in-mvvm-light-v5/):

*In WPF 4 and WPF 4.5, however, there is a catch: The CommandManager will stop working after you upgrade MVVM Light to V5. What you will observe is that your UI elements (buttons, etc) will stop getting disabled/enabled when the RelayCommand’s CanExecute delegate returns false.*

*If you are in a hurry, here is the fix: In any class that uses the RelayCommand, replace the line saying:*

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
```

*with:*

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try with [CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested.aspx).

Anyway this did not help me sometimes in the past. For me the best solution turned out to be to bind the boolean property to the `Button.IsEnabled` dependency property.

In your case something like

```
IsEnabled={Binding IsTestrunInProgress}
```

Comment: Yes, using the binding like you said and it works like a charm.

Comment: This defeats the purpose of using a command in the first place, and only works if your enabled state depends on a single property.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is, the ICommand Property TestrunStartCommand is always returning a new command object whenever it is accessed.

A simple fix is to create the ICommand object once and use it again and again.

```
private ICommand _testRunCommand = null;
public ICommand TestrunStartCommand
{
    get 
    { 
        return _testRunCommand ?? (_testRunCommand = new RelayCommand(TestrunStartExecute, () => !IsTestrunInProgress)); 
    }
}
```

This was quite a simple fix and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to Riegardt Steyn's answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33503341/1964969

If you don't want to change `Command` to `CommandWpf` usage (as that two RelayCommand versions are not compatible inbetween), another workaround could be to not instantiate a command at the declaration place. Use constructor code instead:

```
public class SomeVMClass
{
    // CanExecute won't work:
    // Declaration and instantiation same place
    public RelayCommand MyCommand1 => new RelayCommand(MyBusinessLogic, MyCanExecuteValidator);

    // CanExecute will work
    // Declaration only
    public RelayCommand MyCommand2 { get; private set; }

    public SomeVMClass()
    {
        // Let's instantiate our declared command
        MyCommand2 = new RelayCommand(MyBusinessLogic, MyCanExecuteValidator);
       ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote

In your Command class change CanExcutedChanged to this

```
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }
```

This is example of my command class

```
public class SaveConfigCommand : ICommand
{
    public MyViewModel VM { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public SaveConfigCommand(MyViewModel vm)
    {
        VM = vm;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object? parameter)
    {
        MyObjectModel model = parameter as MyObjectModel;

        if (model == null)
            return false;

        // Validate others properties here 

        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object? parameter)
    {
        VM.MyMethodInViewModel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a `BackgroundWorker` (not necessarily what OP is asking), the `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()` will only work inside the `ProgressChanged` callback and not on the `DoWork` callback.

```
//Not going to work.
private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested, DispatcherPriority.Render);
}

//Works!
private void Worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested, DispatcherPriority.Render);
}
```