# Fody dosent change behavior of button, the button dosent get reevaluated to see if it can get pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, fody-propertychanged

For some reason, I can't activate my `Button`.

In my app, I have a `TextBox`, that gets populated with the file path that the user chooses from a dialog.
I also have a `ComboBox` to let the user choose a language.

What I want to do, is to activate my button *Start*, when the `FilePath` is not empty and the user has selected a language.

```
[AddINotifyPropertyChangedInterface]
public class AudioPageViewModel {

    public string? FilePath { get; set; }

    public bool IsWorking { get; set; }

    public bool CanPress { get; set; }

    public string? SelectedItem { get; set; }

    public List<string>? Languages { get; set; }

    public Visibility CanShow { get; set; }

    public DialogHelper Dialog { get; }

    public Command PickFileCommad { get; set; }

    public Command StartCommand { get; set; }

    public AudioPageViewModel() {
        InitListLanguages();
        Dialog = new DialogHelper();
        CanShow = Visibility.Hidden;
        PickFileCommad = new Command(PickFileAction);
        StartCommand = new Command(StartAction, CanStartAction);
    }

    private bool CanStartAction(object arg) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedItem) ||
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePath)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void StartAction(object obj) {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private void PickFileAction() {
        var filePath = Dialog.GetFilePath(ConstantsHelpers.AUDIO);
        FilePath = filePath;
    }

    private void InitListLanguages() {

        Languages = new List<string>() {
            "English",
            "Spanish"
        };
```

```
<Grid Margin="20">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Button
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Command="{Binding PickFileCommad}"
        Content="Pick a file"
        FontWeight="Bold" />

    <Label
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="0,5,0,0"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
        Content="language of the file" />

    <TextBox
        Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="10,0,10,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        Text="{Binding FilePath}" />

    <ComboBox
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Margin="10,0,10,0"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Languages}">
    </ComboBox>

    <Label
        Grid.Row="3"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="10,0,10,0"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        Content="This will not take long"
        Visibility="{Binding CanShow}" />

    <ui:ProgressRing
        Grid.Row="2"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Width="60"
        Height="60"
        Margin="10,0,10,0"
        IsActive="{Binding IsWorking}" />

    <Button
        Grid.Row="4"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="10,0,10,10"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Content="Start"
        Command="{Binding StartCommand}"
        IsEnabled="{Binding CanPress}" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479303/icommand-canexecute-not-triggering-after-propertychanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key issue is that you use both a `Command` and an `IsEnabled` binding. You should only use one, as they interfere with each other. A command binding will set the enabled state of a button depending on the result of its `CanExceute` method. Binding `IsEnabled` too, will override this. I would suggest to use commands only and move the logic from `CanPress` to the `CanStartAction` method of `StartCommand`.

### Using Commands

Commands signal if they can be executed by their `CanExecute` method result. However, there are different implementations of commands that trigger the reevaluation of this method differently.

#### Relay Command With Command Manager

If you use a command implementation that uses the `RequerySuggested` event, e.g.:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
   add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
   remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}
```

Then removing the `IsEnabled` binding is enoungh, as it is triggered by input in the user interface.

#### Relay Command With Explicit Method

The other variant is a command implementation, where a method is exposed to explicitly reevalute its state, e.g. `RaiseCanExcuteChanged`. In this case, the `CanExecuteChanged` event is raised explicity and the UI element that binds the command is triggered to execute `CanExecute` again and update its own enabled state.

Unfortunately, the *Fody PropertyChanged* library does not support attributes for commands that would trigger reevaluation of can execute. There was already a request, but it was declined and they will not implement it.

- [Extend DependsOnAttribute for commands #281](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/issues/281)

A workaround is to create `On<Property>Changed` methods, which will be called by Fody on changes of the corresponding `<Property>` automatically, see [On_PropertyName_Changed in the Wiki](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki/On_PropertyName_Changed). These methods then call the explicit reevaluation method.

```
public void OnSelectedItemChanged()
{
   StartCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
   Debug.WriteLine("SelectedItem Changed");
}

public void OnFilePathChanged()
{
   StartCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
   Debug.WriteLine("FilePath Changed");
}
```

### Using IsEnabled

When using `IsEnabled` only, you have to move the `CanStartAction` logic to be executed in `CanPress`. In this case this would be an explicit implentation that cannot use Fody.

- [Custom setter #157](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/issues/157)

Additionally, you could not use a command, so a `Click` handler would be an ugly alternative. This is why I strongly recommend you to use commands instead.

Comment: Finally someone that explains, thank you very much for the explanation, I am using MVVM.helpers, a package by James Montemagno (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/mvvm-helpers) that exposes the RaisePropertyChange().

So what I did, is to inherit from BaseViewModel, now what I have to do is delete the canPress, since the button takes care of it